# Pandas: How to split a dataframe into two dataframes by variables (columns)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with columns "Weight", "Rank", "Country", and "Age", ... and several more columns and I need to split the dataframe into continuous variable columns (i.e. weight, age, ) and discrete variable columns.

I was hoping to divide the dataframe into two separate dataframes by column names.
Is this possible?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected results?

Comment: How do you decide whether its continuous or discrete?

Comment: Do you mean the columns with variable that change over time in one dataframe and the variables that are constant in other dataframe . A sample data would be helpful to show the output properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = #your dataframe

df1 = df[['Weight','Age']].copy()

df2 = df[['Rank','Country']].copy()
```